# How do you get stats on a gmod darkrp server to display it on a website/

Tags: mysql, api

I want to display some stats in a website like this:
https://zarpgaming.com/index.php/leaderboards/darkrp/gangs
how do I do this ? I work mostly with front end so I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Choose a backend framework and connect it to the database. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Answer (score -1):

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Wallet</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("yourip","username","pw","databasename"); 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tablename");
        while  ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):

        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['rpname']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['salary']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['wallet']; ?></td>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.13.1/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.13.1/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(".table").DataTable();
</script>
```

this code works
got it from this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UN_BO_qlna8